# How to execute multi-line command in gitlab pipeline script?

Tags: syntax, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

Below is the content of my YAML config for the pipeline and getting the below error while running it. Could you please correct what is wrong here?

**ERROR**

```
$ REGION="us-east-1" # collapsed multi-line command
/scripts-19572064-2902695278/step_script: eval: line 317: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

**YAML CONFIG**

```
  script:
    - . ./build-metadata
    - sh /create-aws-profile.sh
    - >
      REGION="us-east-1"

      while :
      do
          ami_state=$(aws ec2 describe-images --region "$REGION" --image-ids "$US_EAST_AMI" | jq -r .Images[].State)

          case $ami_state in
              available)
                  echo "Now the AMI is available in the $REGION region"
                  break
              ;;
              failed)
                  echo "AMI is failed in $REGION region"
                  break
              ;;
              pending)
                  echo "AMI is still pending in $REGION region"
              ;;
              *)
                  echo "AMI is in the unhandled state: $ami_state"
                  break
              ;;
          esac
          sleep 10
      done

    - aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --region us-east-1 --image-id $US_EAST_AMI_ID --attribute launchPermission --operation-type add --organizational-unit-arns $OU
```

Comment: use `|` not `>` for a multiline string that preserves linebreaks (rather than collapsing them).

Comment: @sytech If I use `|` I'm getting the error `step_script: eval: line 303: syntax error near unexpected token `-'`

Comment: No, that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @sytech If I use `|` I'm getting the error `step_script: eval: line 303: syntax error near unexpected token `-'`

Comment: Another issue is that you're using colons `:` in your script, the parser thinks  `:` defines a YAML keyword, as per GitLab docs: "To use commands that contain a colon, you should wrap the whole command in single quotes. You might need to change existing single quotes (') into double quotes ("):"

Comment: @javierlga So In my case, it should be like `'while :'`

Comment: @javierlga Still, I'm unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: @wolfgang to bring this to your notice to find what is wrong here. I referred to the page https://yaml-multiline.info but could not find what was wrong with my script.